# Array Broadcasting Error in OpenCV Docs Example for Laplacian Blend

Tags: python, opencv

I have found what I believe to be problematic code [in the opencv python docs for pyramid blends](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html). The sample code found at the bottom does not work, throwing an error with array broadcasting:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (240,135) (240,136).
```

I am new to opencv and array broadcasting is a bit new to me as well, so if anyone has suggestions on debugging this code it would be much appreciated. [The same issue has been pointed out here in an example that repurposes the code](https://gist.github.com/royshil/0b20a7dd08961c83e210024a4a7d841a), but nobody has answered it yet. I've perused the other open threads on this error for on array broadcasting and I can't see how to get my way out of this by transforming the matrices.

Comment: Your cannot combine two image that have different dimensions. The second image has one more column than the first.

Comment: the example code assumes the image's size to be a multiple of a certain power of two (depends on number of pyramid layers), because then `pyrUp(pyrDown(im)).shape == im.shape`

Answer (score 2):

Trying the [sample code in the OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html), I'm getting the following error:

> (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither
> 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number
> of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function
> 'cv::arithm_op'

The cause seems to be this line: `L = cv.subtract(gpA[i - 1], GE)`. It appears that the tutorial is attempting to subtract a larger array from a small one, so there's a broadcasting error. Maybe an issue should be submitted pointing out this error.

Now, trying the `Gist` you also posted, some modifications are needed. The code uses the deprecated `xrange()` function from `Python 2.x`. Just for completeness, here's the modified code for `Python 3.x`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def Laplacian_Pyramid_Blending_with_mask(A, B, m, num_levels=6):
    # assume mask is float32 [0,1]

    # generate Gaussian pyramid for A,B and mask
    GA = A.copy()
    GB = B.copy()
    GM = m.copy()
    gpA = [GA]
    gpB = [GB]
    gpM = [GM]
    for i in range(num_levels):
        GA = cv2.pyrDown(GA)
        GB = cv2.pyrDown(GB)
        GM = cv2.pyrDown(GM)
        gpA.append(np.float32(GA))
        gpB.append(np.float32(GB))
        gpM.append(np.float32(GM))

    # generate Laplacian Pyramids for A,B and masks
    lpA = [gpA[num_levels - 1]]  # the bottom of the Lap-pyr holds the last (smallest) Gauss level
    lpB = [gpB[num_levels - 1]]
    gpMr = [gpM[num_levels - 1]]
    for i in range(num_levels - 1, 0, -1):
        # Laplacian: subtarct upscaled version of lower level from current level
        # to get the high frequencies
        LA = np.subtract(gpA[i - 1], cv2.pyrUp(gpA[i]))
        LB = np.subtract(gpB[i - 1], cv2.pyrUp(gpB[i]))
        lpA.append(LA)
        lpB.append(LB)
        gpMr.append(gpM[i - 1])  # also reverse the masks

    # Now blend images according to mask in each level
    LS = []
    for la, lb, gm in zip(lpA, lpB, gpMr):
        ls = la * gm + lb * (1.0 - gm)
        LS.append(ls)

    # now reconstruct
    ls_ = LS[0]
    for i in range(1, num_levels):
        ls_ = cv2.pyrUp(ls_)
        ls_ = cv2.add(ls_, LS[i])

    return ls_


# Read input images:
A = cv2.imread('orange01.png')
B = cv2.imread('apple01.png')

m = np.zeros_like(A, dtype='float32')
m[:,int(A.shape[1]/2):] = 1  # make the mask half-and-half
lpb = Laplacian_Pyramid_Blending_with_mask(A, B, m, 5)

# Write result to disk:
cv2.imwrite("lpb.png",lpb)

# Convert float image to uint8:
img = lpb.astype(np.uint8)

# Show image:
cv2.imshow("LPB", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I'm testing the code with images obtained from the OpenCV tutorial: [Apple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSlmf.png) and [Orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHVr8.png). These images are of size `240` x `240`. An even size. But more importantly, the image can now be subtracted by the largest pyramid. This is the result of testing the linked images:

[image]

Which seems to match the result shown on the official documentation. My suggestion here would be to slightly resize your test images to increase their `width`, which is the dimension that apparently is causing the broadcasting error in your code. In my test I upscaled the images from `239` x `239` to `240` x `240`.